# Resharper Hotkeys

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, resharper, hotkeys

I just started using resharper and I am trying to learn all the hotkeys - Is there a list of all the hotkeys somewhere for the standard install? Something this is possibly in printable format.

Comment: As someone looking to purchase ReSharper soon, this would be great to know.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

See [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/documentation.html):

- [ReSharper 4.5 Default Keymap: Visual Studio scheme](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/docs/ReSharper45DefaultKeymap.pdf)
- [ReSharper 4.5 Default Keymap: ReSharper 2.x / IDEA scheme](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/docs/ReSharper45DefaultKeymap2.pdf)

Resharper 7.0:

- [ReSharper 7.0 Default Keymap: Visual Studio scheme](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/docs/ReSharper70DefaultKeymap_VS_scheme.pdf)
- [ReSharper 7.0 Default Keymap: ReSharper 2.x / IDEA scheme](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/docs/ReSharper70DefaultKeymap_IDEA_scheme.pdf)

Resharper 8.0:

- [ReSharper 8.0 Default Keymap: Visual Studio scheme](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/docs/ReSharper80DefaultKeymap_VS_scheme.pdf)
- [ReSharper 8.0 Default Keymap: ReSharper 2.x / IDEA scheme](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/docs/ReSharper80DefaultKeymap_IDEA_scheme.pdf)

All files are in PDF.

Comment: Note that while these are valid links, they refer to keymaps for R# 4.5. To get keymaps for the current R# version, go to ReSharper documentation page: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/

Comment: The links above are not valid anymore. For ReSharper 10 please follow this link:[ReSharper keymap](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/docs/ReSharper_DefaultKeymap_IDEAscheme.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the PDF keymaps that JetBrains officially maintains and updates with every new release, you can also take a look at [Keymaps for ReSharper](http://keymaps.forresharper.org/) - a ReSharper plug-in by Howard van Rooijen that helps you learn R# shortcuts in either keymap.

Answer (score 1):

You bet.  Go to this page:  [Resharper Documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/documentation.html) 
and near the top are 3 download links to the various keymap PDF's - I use the Visual Studio Scheme so that's the PDF I downloaded.

Of further note, the link to the main online help docs in on the page as well.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the lists for the differnent keyboard layouts are available as PDF [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/documentation.html)